# ngReactGrid issue within requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Experimenting with [ngReactGrid](https://github.com/josebalius/ngReactGrid/) I've got stuck on an issue where the grid component (ngReactGrid.js:38) throws an error of *React is undefined*. What could cause this, as the requirejs setup file includes

```
"shim": {
"angular": {
  exports: 'angular'
},
'react': {
  exports: 'React'
},
"ngReactGrid": {
  deps: ['angular', 'react']
}
```

}

http://plnkr.co/edit/MwxbGnx1xu3gxfhY7ENM

The same code outside of requirejs works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bA0wpPYH2MDzAXTP6T5d?p=preview)

```
    require.config({
      "baseUrl": "/js",
      "paths": {
        "angular": "https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular",
        "react": "http://fb.me/react-0.10.0",
        "ngReactGrid": "https://rawgit.com/josebalius/ngReactGrid/master/build/js/ngReactGrid",

        'app': 'http://run.plnkr.co/zmcl7fFM2eAPf9Ew/app'
      },
      "shim": {
        "angular": {
          exports: 'angular'
        },
        "ngReactGrid": {
          deps: ['angular', 'react']
        }
      }
    });

    require(['app'], function( app) {

      var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);

      angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap($html, [app.name]);
      });

});
```

Hope this will help

Comment: thanks, digging more into it after your response I've found that the call to React outside of requirejs managed to get things working in plnkr http://embed.plnkr.co/Rhnf7mpt8gwTfEgzoATl/preview.